# Involutions in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, involutions

Define involution in an associative ring $k$ with identity as a map
$k\rightarrow k$ mapping each $\alpha \in k$ to $\bar{\alpha}\in k$ such that

i) $\overline{\bar{\alpha}} = \alpha$

ii) $\overline{\alpha + \beta} = \bar{\alpha} + \bar{\beta}$

iii) $\overline{\alpha \beta} = \bar{\beta} \bar{\alpha}$

Using this, how can we show that the only involution in $\mathbb{Q}$ is the
identity map?

Comment: Note that $$1= \overline {\overline{1}} = \overline { 1 \cdot \overline {1}} = \overline {1} \cdot \overline {\overline {1}}=\overline {1} \cdot 1 = \overline {1}$$ so that your map must be a ring morphism preserving the identity. But $\Bbb{Q}$ has only one such morphism: the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Show $\overline{1} = 1$
- Show $\overline{k} = k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ using ii)
- Show $\overline{p/q} = p/q$ with iii).

Comment: Thanks! So, here is what I got:

Comment: 1) $\bar{1}=\bar{1} \cdot 1 = \overline{1 \cdot \bar{1}} = \overline{\bar{1}} = 1$; 2) $\overline{n+1} = \bar{n} + 1$, so by induction we get $\bar{n} = n$ for all integer $n$; 3) $\overline{x^{-1}} \overline{x} = \overline{x^{-1} x} = 1$ (and same on the right), so $\overline{x}^{-1} = \overline{x^{-1}}$, so $\overline{p q^{-1}} = \overline{p} \overline{q^{-1}} = p q^{-1}$.

Comment: For 2) you need a little argument for negative numbers. Maybe it would be better to show $\overline{-x} = - \overline{x}$ in general. This follows easily since $\overline{x} + \overline{-x} = \overline{x - x} = \overline{0} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The ring $\mathbb{Q}$ is commutative, so by $iii)$ your involution is actually a ring automorphism, and they are known to be trivial on $\mathbb{Q}$.